# Java audio conversion fails, Unsupported conversion: FLAC from MPEG2L3 22050.0 Hz

Tags: java, javasound, flac

I have an AudioInputStream, and I want a FLAC AudioInputStream.

I am using the FlacEncoding.FLAC from the jflac library.

I added the mp3plugin.jar to the classpath to handle mp3.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

import org.kc7bfi.jflac.sound.spi.FlacEncoding;

public AudioInputStream getFlacStream(AudioInputStream ais) {
    FlacEncoding encoding = FlacEncoding.FLAC;
    AudioInputStream flacStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(encoding,
            ais);
    return flacStream;
}
```

but it gives error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported conversion: FLAC from MPEG2L3 22050.0 Hz, unknown bits per sample, mono, unknown frame size, unknown frame rate, 
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:876)
    at FlacConverter.getFlacStream(FlacConverter.java:43)
    at FlacConverter.getFlacBytes(FlacConverter.java:36)
    at FlacConverter.main(FlacConverter.java:25)
```

**update**:

when I call

```
AudioSystem.getTargetEncodings(ais.getFormat());
```

I get an array with only one encoding:

```
PCM_SIGNED
```

Comment: And ..do you have a question?

Comment: Yes. How do I make the conversion work?

Comment: I suspect the conversion is failing because of all those `unknown` values in the MP3 format.  Try it with the MP3 files linked [here](http://pscode.org/media/#sound).

Comment: I tried a few of them, all gave the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jflac currently only supports decoding from FLAC not encoding to FLAC.

I see there is a javaFlacEncoder project on sourceforge which might do what you want.